# Get a list of all existing partitions in couchDb

Tags: couchdb, partition

I have a partitioned CouchDB database. Is there any query to get a list of all partitions in a particular database? I have not found anything like that in CouchDb documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider reading this thread in CouchDB dev mail list: https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/re1791021d16acc04adaf414eba31950063065e1e8761f0307dcc8bfd%40%3Cdev.couchdb.apache.org%3E

In short, there’s no endpoint for this, but you can make a view or traverse partitions incrementally.

Answer (score 0):

There is no endpoint that *just* lists partitioned state for all db's, however the [/_dbs_info](http://127.0.0.1:5984/_utils/docs/api/server/common.html#dbs-info) endpoint is close enough with a little processing.

Here is a naïve script I spun up using [nano](https://github.com/apache/couchdb-nano) and [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/) 10.  The script displays database names, prefixed with an asterisk (*) if the database is partitioned.

```
const nano = require("nano")("http://user:password@localhost:5984");

(async () => {
    console.log("db list (* = partitioned)");
    (
        await nano.request({
            method: "POST",
            path: "/_dbs_info",
            body: { keys: await nano.db.list() },
        })
    ).forEach((doc) => console.log(`${doc.info.props.partitioned ? "*" : " "} ${doc.key}`));
})();
```

I say naïve because this script doesn't account for such things as systems with massive numbers of databases, smart security, whether `props` exists etc. - so YMMV.